# Error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type express "Application"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-modules

Recently one of our old written micro-service (Nodejs V10 + Typescript V7.0.1) start throwing following errors:

```
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts(31,14): error TS2339: Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Application'.
src/app.ts(48,14): error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Application'.
src/app.ts(49,14): error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Application'.
src/app.ts(50,14): error TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Application'.
src/app.ts(51,14): error TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Application'.
src/app.ts(52,14): error TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Application'.
```

**Code Environment**

We are running our code in docker-compose in order to maintain the old nodejs and typescript versions, Dockerfile content

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Same code working on local system but not on development server. No relevant information found on google, could you please suggest what might be the reason for this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a lot of R&D, We come to know that **ts-node** & **typescript** npms needs to be updated. Following command fix the problem.

```
npm i ts-node --save-dev && npm i typescript --save-dev
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 10):

[TS 4.0 is not supported on DT anymore.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/7a77b08d606efd24bf755af6638246d235840185)

Try using a previous version of the packages

- @types/express (4.17.13)
- @types/express-serve-static-core (4.17.30)

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, but your answer did. Thank you. Running `npm install @types/express` solved it for me.

Comment: Same here, it worked for me. But I'd suggest to install like `npm install -D @types/express`

Comment: Was trying to make an old project run but was encountering the same issue.
This comment saved me! I had no @types/express-serve-static-core dependency installed. I think it automatically just installed the latest version... so I went to npm and searched for my projects TypeScript version and downloaded the matching package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express-serve-static-core/v/4.17.24?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 0):

First steps are
Uninstall typscript and ts-node from node project

```
npm uninstall typescript ts-node
```

Now install them again

```
npm install ts-node --save-dev
npm install typescript -g 
npm install typescript --save-dev
```

Now run project, if it didn't work, check below methods.

Make sure you have @types/express installed (npm install @types/express) and that your tsconfig.json includes "esModuleInterop": true and "types": ["node"] in its compilerOptions.

If you've done all of the above and still encountering the error, it might be worth checking if your node_modules directory is corrupted or outdated. In that case, you could try deleting the node_modules directory and reinstalling dependencies (npm install or yarn install). This often helps to resolve any typings-related issues.